# Error when issuing count(*) on a correlated subquery

Tags: amazon-redshift

Count(*) returns two different results, even though the conditions don't significantly change.
Here's query that should return the same value in count(*) column, regardless of the commented/uncommented part:

```
select count(*) as regular_count, some_date, sum((call_count>0)::int) as active_count
  --  , count(distinct random_corresponding_varchar) -- uncomment this part accordingly
FROM (
       SELECT
         es.random_corresponding_varchar,
         DATE(some_date) AS some_date,
         (SELECT count(*)
          FROM inner_sample cs
          WHERE cs.random_varchar = es.random_corresponding_varchar) AS call_count
       FROM outer_sample es
       GROUP BY es.random_corresponding_varchar, DATE(some_date)
     ) as a
group by some_date
order by some_date
```

Sample scenario (just blindly run this, data is irrelevant here for the most part):

```
CREATE TABLE inner_sample
(
  id VARCHAR(256),
  random_varchar VARCHAR(256)
);
CREATE TABLE outer_sample
(
  random_corresponding_varchar VARCHAR(384),
  some_date DATE
);
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('a4d099a37563aef9825f6ae70b3e7c56e0ad81aa', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('8a6d2dff4e439c60bed044562db7af6e9e30af5e', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('4681f4a47d043def97d4d95aaf189491d51e8503', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('35932f4dd18260abf098b17c4abc2acd2134de62', 'vcb0udhl49');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('31db53f5806318cb4a4c2938c0dbff35f08fb7d9', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('0996af69d67e5397dae2f37771c2bc031251c99a', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('1b866177db992492dd7a11f24060c2f5ef110f99', 'qurrkyspzb');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('4fe969fa1c558626e9bd39c8a01e5f5cc60ebc03', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('8995f0f27737acddcb0c5999a383fa4500682daa', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('2e0e5a7f49924fa3c949e87c23c17eda9ab82711', 'vcb0udhl49');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('de3b7c7a829973bfdfaf91fe87ed3658466cb1d9', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('3f9cce1e9fa789a906ce235f7a566369830a322b', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('19f41e2e69601ce965673311b1598084186fbee1', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('d05c6320801ef167cbe454bb422bceab809080a0', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('70e051422c1851c6ac2aa8d7cd6d9271cb6dcb1a', 'vcb0udhl49');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('1d62b71119263da45990dd48f934977f1b84be91', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('98aca15bde5006cc70d6f84dbf323ec0e9bb45a2', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('508e369d792bfcc314be35b3fffbed3a9561a100', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('9bb73d890ad773ed60d6d510e6a5a412dd55c49f', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('17a8cd7387831813eaa0117fdb8e6c4d2e3091fc', 'rziyhrwoj2');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('0d9eee14d164507dbb797088b50cc16bdbba377e', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('b620deb2afdd11195e578b1696d5bb488957b87f', 'wcsna7t3zg');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('017d7e19d4ed21a2dbf74d92cb1202448168c0c0', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('6ec79f8c688026a7ff40135e8254b53c24962abc', 'vcb0udhl49');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('51c15f3306cbb4018f56495b7cc92d93f74fa79e', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.inner_sample (id, random_varchar) VALUES ('b80b9c87c09538f48ec55c78537089f99231213a', 'jdp5htrtlx');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('n3ptpo8upy', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('i5mqqg5xlm', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('mxpr0vazlj', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('uenymh253f', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('cwufxsms1x', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('yacnezje0u', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('jdp5htrtlx', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('riq1jav7xt', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('vcb0udhl49', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('qurrkyspzb', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('rziyhrwoj2', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('dno31jc9ke', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('iqvggayhwg', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('rbfdfqsdrw', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('zhf29sxwki', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('wcsna7t3zg', '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO public.outer_sample (random_corresponding_varchar, some_date) VALUES ('qysvkjf3my', '2017-08-01');
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an example of a correlated subquery that is not supported in RedShift:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html

> this kind of subquery contains one or more correlations between its columns and the columns produced by the outer query...
>
> The query planner uses a query rewrite method called subquery decorrelation to optimize several patterns of correlated subqueries for execution in an MPP environment. A few types of correlated subqueries follow patterns that Amazon Redshift can't decorrelate and does not support...

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)